# Jquery append statement not working

Tags: jquery, append

I have some jQuery AJAX code that takes the contents of a text-area and adds it to a MySQL database.  At the end of this I would like to add those contents to a `div`.  This div already has other `divs` inside so I think I should use the `.append()` function to add a new `div`.  However, this isn't working.

`.commentContainer` is the `div` I would like to add the response to.  The output of `comment.php` is:

```
 <div>$comment</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('document').ready(function () {
       $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var $form = $(this);
         var commentbox = $(this).children('.commentBox');

         $.ajax({
             "url": $form.attr("action"),
             "data": $form.serialize(),
             "type": $form.attr("method"),
             success: function (response) {
                     commentbox.val('');
                     $(this).closest('.commentContainer').append(response);  //this line isnt working
               }
          });
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: put an alert and check if you are getting expected response.

Comment: @dku.rajkumar when i alert the line that isnt working i get: [object Object]

Comment: is `.commentContainer` a parent of the form because`.closest()` looks up the parent chain only?

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, commentContainer is a parent of form

Comment: If you put `alert($(this))` into the `success` function, does it return the element you expect it to?

Comment: @DavidThomas it returned [object Object]

Comment: Then try `alert(this.id + ', ' + this.tagName.toLowerCase());`, and see if it returns the `id` and element that you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already caching the `$(this)` selection in the `$form` variable, just reference it instead of using `$(this)` all over the place:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form      = $(this),
            commentbox = $form.children('.commentBox');

        $.ajax({
            url     : $form.attr("action"),
            data    : $form.serialize(),
            type    : $form.attr("method"),
            success : function (response) {
                commentbox.val('');
                $form.closest('.commentContainer').append(response);  //this line isnt working
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for posting your HTML, it appears as though the `.commentContainer` element is a sibling of the `form` element so you want to change:

```
$form.closest('.commentContainer').append(response);
```

To:

```
$form.siblings('.commentContainer').append(response);
```

Comment: Then if the `commentbox` element's value is being reset that means that `$form.closest()` isn't selecting any elements or the response from the server is nothing. Try `console.log(response)` inside your callback function to see what appears in your error console. If you can provide some HTML I can suggest the proper method of selection.

Comment: you're solution worked!.  just for future reference, i thought that .closest() looks above $form.  isn't .commentContainer above the form? thanks

Comment: @user802370 `.closest` looks for ancestors of the element, to check-out all the different types of DOM traversal available in jQuery, check this out: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ (I highly recommend looking through this list, it can help you in the future)

Comment: thank you for your help.  i just have one more question.   how could i make the response fadeIn?

Comment: `$form.siblings('.commentContainer').hide().append(response).fadeIn();` This will hide the `.commentContainer` element, append the new HTML, and then fade it back in. You can add a parameter to the `fadeIn()` function to specify the duration of the fade: `.fadeIn(750)` will take three quarters of a second to fade-in.